# My database HotOrNotdb is not displaying in the list of databases in the command prompt

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created a database called "HotOrNotdb" in the SQLite database, with the help of Eclipse. I can see the database file in DDMS perspective --> File Explorer --> data --> data folder. But, when I try to open the database from command prompt, I am unable to do any operations on it and it is not displaying at all in the list of databases. I have used the following command to view the databases that are already created.
sqlite>.databases

and it returned only two databases - main and temp. I did bot create them manually, but I don't know how they are created.

Comment: The `.databases` command shows any databases that are attached to the currently opened database. How are you trying to open the DB from the command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have imported the database file to my Pc and opened it with SQLiteBrowser. We can do this even with SQLite Manager, which is a firefox plug-in. I did some modifications with these tools and again from DDMS FileExplorer, I have imported into the emulator. This worked for me now. This is better than using sqlite.exe as stated in my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying for my query. My problem got solved now. I did the following things to open the database. First I have installed SQLite3.exe by downloading it online. Then, I have opened the sqlite3 database with the following commands -

C:\Program Files\SQLite ODBC Driver> sqlite.exe

This opens me a window, where I can select the database from my computer. Prior to that, I will have to pull my database file from the device into my computer. The database file is located at /data/data folder of file explorer in DDMS Perspective. Then, after opening that file from the command prompt, we can start querying the database as usually.

Some times, because of emulator crashes, this type of error occurs. The same happened in my application. I have recreated a new emulator and started running the application in that worked for me. I did this wothout using SQLite3.exe